# Magento2 : How to add custom layout in admin panel at catagories->Design tab?

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1, layout-update

I am new in Magento2. I create a new customized theme for eCommerce store. 
Now ,i want to add the `custom layout` in admin panel at **categories->design tab at layout dropdown**.

How should I do it.

Or I want to display the custom category page at frontend which is in tabular form means when I click on any category  it display one page which is 1 column and in tabular format which contain different column.

First column for product name and I want when user click on product name or sku specified over their, it redirect to product view page. Please can anyone help me to resolve this query. for details of my question have look on attached screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For adding custom layout in admin panel I use below steps:-

**1)** In project folder go to

```
vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/page_layout/
```

here create `xml` file which want to show in `admin->categories->design tab->in layout dropdown.`

**2)** Add the newly created xml entry in below file

```
vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/layout.xml
```

Then automatically the custom layout design pages will appear in admin layout.